# thymeleaf +bootstrap+spring boot+postgresql

Tags: spring-mvc, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

! Hi, everyone.I'm making a small application and I need to download an image from the database and display this image on the page. A image is the background of a page . There should be buttons (links) on the image - which can be added. I mean, you can click on the image, a new form will open to add a button (link), fill in the information, save it to the database and then display it in the place where the click on the image was made.

I added getting an image from the database and added rows to the whole image

```css
#tableBgImage {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 700px;
    width: 1170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

        <div id="tableBgImage" th:style="'background-image:url(' + ${'/addressBuilding/display?id='+ id} + ');'">
          <div class="row" style="height: 50px">
                <div  class="col-md-2" style="width: 65px" > <div>
                <div  class="col-md-2" style="width: 65px" > <div>
                <div  class="col-md-2" style="width: 65px" > <div>
                <div  class="col-md-2" style="width: 65px" > <div>
                <div  class="col-md-2" style="width: 65px" > <div>
                <div  class="col-md-2" style="width: 65px" > <div>
        
 </div>
```

and I repeat `<div class="row" style="height: 50px"` with `<div  class="col-md-2` to cover the whole image. I'm not sure if this is correct. Maybe I should use some other approach?

I don't understand how I can make each row editable to add buttons(links) and display buttons (links) if they were previously saved in the database?